# .gitignore no funciona ignorando una subcarpeta de una carpeta ignorada

Tags: git

he intentado implementar las soluciones de: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder/

sin exito.

Con lo siguiente en el **gitignore**, no ignora ninguna subcarpeta ni a node_modules, ejemplo de mi archivo :

```
!node_modules/
node_modules/*
!node_modules/node-dht-sensor-chip/
node_modules/*
node_modules/*
!node_modules/node-dht-sensor-chip/
!node-dht-sensor-chip/
!node_modules/node-dht-sensor-chip/
!node-dht-sensor-chip/*
!*node-dht-sensor-chip/
```

Con lo siguiente ignora todo de la carpeta ***node_modules***, incluida

```
node_modules
node_modules/
**/node_modules/*
!**/node_modules/node-dht-sensor-chip/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muchas gracias. Pero ya solucione el problema creando un .gitignore dentro de la carpeta node_modules y simplemente puse en él:

> *
>
> !node-dht-sensor-chip/*

Answer (score 5):

Esta bien lo que comentas, pero creastes el .gitignore despues de finalizado el proyecto; debes limpiar el cache del proyecto **git**

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m "Limpieza de Cache"
```

merito https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451535/gitignore-is-not-working

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ya había intentado esto cuando descargaba el proyecto y al hacerle debug se creaban unos archivos de manera automática, pero me modificaba el proyecto de tal manera que lo dañaba. Esto lo solucione borrando las carpetas de cache del repositorio remoto